# Connecting to AWS mysql with mysql front software

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to connect to my mysql server on aws ec2 ubuntu. I put in the public DNS for the server and user and password for root.

I can't get in, is there something special I have to do on the server side regarding ports or something? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to access MySQL directly over the internet? If so, that's a bad idea. Instead, just set mysql to listen on localhost and then access it via an ssh tunnel - this is much more secure.